# How can I create a UIImageGIFRepresentation function?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, gif

Using Swift 3 for iOS, I am able to use cinemagraphs (animated gifs) that I download through a UIWebView without any problem. I am also trying to get them to work from the iPhone library. However, there is no way that I have found to get the data representation of a GIF stored in the library.

Someone will say that "there is no such thing as an animated gif in the library", but they would be wrong. Go to a web page in Safari, long-tap on an animated gif, and save it to your library. Then send a text message to yourself and copy in that image from the library. You'll see that the animated gif is intact and works perfectly.

My problem is that I need to copy the image from the library programmatically, and I'm not sure how to do it with no specific function built for GIFs. I would like to create the equivalent of UIImagePNGRepresentation or UIImageJPEGRespresentation, except for GIF images. Alternatively, is there a way to get an image from the library as a UIImage, so I don't have to try to convert it to data?

Here's the code I am using for other image formats:
* Edited to be latest version *

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let origImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let refURL : URL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! URL
    var resizedImage: UIImage!
    var ext: String!

    ext = refURL.pathExtension

    if ext == "GIF" {
        resizedImage = origImage
    } else {
        resizedImage = resizeImage(origImage: origImage, ext: ext)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
        self.photoUpdated(newImage: resizedImage)
    })

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

For GIFs, I tried the following, using the [SwiftGif](https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif) project, which was not successful:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: refURL.absoluteString, withExtension: "GIF")
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url!)

let advTimeGif = UIImage.gifWithData(data)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: advTimeGif)
newImage = imageView.image
```

Anyone have any suggestions as to how I might get this to work? Thanks.

Edit:

I figured out a few more pieces of the puzzle. Specifically, I can get the image name and the local path to it.

```
let refURL : URL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! URL
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first! as String
let localPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory).appendingPathComponent(imageName)
let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
```

Still can't figure out how to get it from there to Data.

Comment: Up-voted. It's well-known that GIF isn't supported in iOS natively, also known (also by the questioner I believe) that animated GIFs are simply individual GIFs with animation (ever open one in Preview?). What I think needs to be done (and no, I don't know how @Lastmboy) is to - in code - open **all** individual GIFs. From there you can easily code them into an animated UIImageView.

Comment: I posted an answer below that works for me with Swift 3. I had to take and manipulate the SwiftGif code a little bit, but it should work if you follow my instructions. It will allow you to use the file name of a GIF image and use it as a `UIImageView`'s image.

Comment: For your PNG and JPEG cases, why are you encoding the images to data and then immediately decoding them? You don't seem to be doing anything with that data, so if you're passing `UIImage`s on to something that needs a `UIImage`, you can just pass the original image you got from the picker.

Comment: And your SwiftGif case fails long before you get to the SwiftGif part -- you're looking up an absolute URL (`refURL.absoluteString`) in your app bundle. Just pass `refURL` to SwiftGif's `gif(url:)` function.

Comment: @rickster, you make a great point. I was told I had to do that to get them to the right image format. However, it did seem a bit odd to me. Therefore, I stripped out that code and am just using the UIImage obtained from the info statement. Unfortunately, it doesn't help with the animated gif, which still loses it's animation. Much easier for the other ones, though.

Comment: @Lastmboy - I now understand your issue much more clearly. I apologize for my inappropriate answer. If you're trying to get a user to select a GIF from their photo library, that's much more complicated. I think that if you could find a way to convert the GIF to `Data` similar to how you call `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_:compressionQuality:)` it might be possible. The only problem is I really don't know how you'd accomplish that. As someone else mentioned, GIFs are actually an array of images that animate.

Comment: @Pierce - yup, that's exactly where I'm stuck. It works fine if I use the URL to a GIF on the web. However, I get that back as a Data variable, which converts just fine with SwiftGif. Can't figure out how to get it out of the library as Data, though. The URL from the image picker comes out as 

`assets-library://asset/asset.GIF?id=4DA836EC-3BE8-40EB-807F-4F980D03B29C&ext=GIF`

 but I'm unable to obtain the image using that address. I thought maybe there was a way to reference a library image by internal url.